# PHP To Show Title From Referring URL

Tags: php

I need to display title from referring URL and here is the code I'm using to achieve that:

```
<?php   
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$url_to_load = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$f = file_get_contents($url_to_load);
$p1 = strpos($f, "<title>");//position start
$qe = substr($f, $p1);//string from start position
$p2 = strpos($qe, "</title>");//position end
$query = substr($qe, 7, $p2-2);//cuts from start position +7 (<title>) untill end position -2...
echo $query;}
else{
$ref_url = 'No Reffering URL'; // show failure message
}//end else no referer set
echo "$ref_url";
?>
```

When i visit page with this code from URL that has the following code:

```
<title>Title Of Referrer</title>
```

Code works, but there is still the piece of the closing  tag and when i check source code this is what i'll get:

```
Title Of Referrer</tit
```

What i need to change to remove the closing  tag completely?

Comment: Note that there may be multiple `<title>` tags in a document.

Comment: You have missed some code in your copy/paste so what you are showing makes little sense

Comment: @arkascha The question is about a referring URL, so it's HTML. Therefore, only one title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = substr($qe, 7, $p2-7);//cuts from start position +7 (<title>) untill end position -2...
```

You only subtract 2 at the end on end title but you add 7 on start title.
Try the code above and see if that works

EDIT:
Another solution is to do like this.

```
 $query = strip_tags(substr($qe, 0, $p2));
```

This saves all of the title tags but then delete them with strip_tags()

EDIT2:
There are some other things in the code I would suggest.

```
$f = file_get_contents($url_to_load);
$query = strip_tags(substr($f, strpos($f, "<title>"),  strpos($f, "</title>")));
```

This code brings it down to two lines of code and uses fewer variables. You can also get ridd of $f, but it may be useful to something else and it's only one variable.

Comment: @Peter No problem! I updated the answer with a shorter code for you. And I would be happy if you would accept the answer too ;-)