# str_replace with a variable character

Tags: php, string

I'm wondering if what I need is even possible. I have a string and I want to replace a portion of it by another string nothing hard BUT the string that I want to replace has some 'dynamic' characters.

i have a string that contains:

> http://someurl.com/whatever?page=*

where * can be any number

I need to have:

> http://someurl.com/whatever?page=*#/somestring

where #/somestring is hardcoded

Comment: If you have a dynamic string portion there you want to look at `preg_replace()` and use a simple regex for it.

Comment: Are the additional characters always going to come at the end of the string? If so you can just append the extra portion: $string .= '#/somestring';

Comment: the thing is that the string is a bunch of html code and the portions that i want to modify are spread out within that string

Comment: If you want to modify html, then use a DOM parser.

Comment: you can simply place the {replaceString} and then
str_replace('{replaceString}', originalString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested you could use a regex for these sort of things; in your case I would suggest something like this:

```
$sub = 'http://someurl.com/whatever?page=23';
$new = preg_replace('/\?page=([0-9]+)/', '?page=$1#/something', $sub);

echo $sub;
echo '</br>';
echo $new;
```

It prints:

```
http://someurl.com/whatever?page=23
http://someurl.com/whatever?page=23#/something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos() to find the start position and end position of the string.
Then you just use str_replace to edit the link.

Look at my earlier answer here: [PHP To Show Title From Reffering URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678250/php-to-show-title-from-reffering-url/36678340?noredirect=1#comment60946965_36678340)
In your case you should not use strip_tags, but the rest is quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it:

```
$string="http://someurl.com/whatever?page=129833";
$replacement="#/somestring";
echo preg_replace('/(http:\/\/someurl\.com\/.*?page=[0-9]+)/','\1'.$replacement,$string);
```

It prints:

> http://someurl.com/whatever?page=129833#/somestring